# Should questions regarding public perception of skeptic issues be allowed?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, asking-questions

I suspect my question title is a little vague, but the issue I am questioning is based on the closure of this question:

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1598/has-a-legal-case-ever-been-brought-against-vendors-of-homepathic-products-close

I understand that it is not strictly on-topic and closure is fine given the current FAQ. However, I think this forum would be a good place to discuss why issues such as homeopathy do not come under more scrutiny by the public and by regulating authorities.

Could (and should) we find a way to reword the FAQ and rescope the site to allow such questions? Or is there a fear that this would this lead to a situation where too many questions become vague and open ended

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your argument basically boils down to this:

> My questions and others of its kind would be questions that are interesting to skeptics. I am sure all proponents of evidence-based medicine would love to know the answer.

While that may be true, that line of reasoning would apply to so many things. How would you amend the FAQ to include your questions, but not be a huge loophole that makes practically everything on-topic? I don't think that's possible. Thats why we limit ourselves to *applying* skepticism.

We can't be the place where people ask their "I was always curious" questions.

Comment: I think that is a fair summary of my question. I am not sure that allowing questions related directly to skeptic issues is a "huge loophole", but if the intention of the site is to purely answer direct skeptical questions then fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

I think that we have to be very careful as to what we allow on site. Many questions may appear on-topic, but they will hardly receive any good answer from a community of skeptics.

We are not a community of lawyers, yet your question was about a law precedent. Wouldn't your question be answered much better on [this site proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/24586/laws-legal-questions)? It would, as it would be perfectly on-topic there, and answered by law specialists.

There are many other cases, as well: many [questions have been migrated to physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7615/what-is-in-the-space-between-a-nucleus-of-an-atom-and-its-electrons), for example, because they get better answers. We are not a community of physicists, either.

I stand by our current FAQ.

Comment: I was not asking for a legal opinion, I was asking if cases had been brought. I agree that the question, possibly reworded could also be asked on a legal forum.